# android - loopj: User-space exception

Tags: android, loopj

I encountered such a problem. I am use loopj in my android project.

```
02-26 15:57:38.247: E/AsyncHttpRH(2661): User-space exception detected! 02-26 15:57:38.247: E/AsyncHttpRH(2661): java.lang.NullPointerException 02-26 15:57:38.247: E/AsyncHttpRH(2661): at com.example.ProgramActivity$1.onSuccess(ProgramActivity.java:125)
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: how did u fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you pass your context as getApplicationContext().
Say you have a HelloWorld activity, you can get context as - 
`context = HelloWorldActivity.this;`